# Using rspec to test tableless model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, testing, rspec

I wanted to test a model without a corresponding table. Here is the model:

```
class ContactMessage

  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :sender_name, :sender_email, :subject, :content, :recipient_name, :recipient_email

  validates_presence_of :sender_name
  validates_format_of :sender_email, :with => /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,}$/i
  validates_presence_of :subject
  validates_length_of :content, :minimum => 10

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

  def sender
    sender_name + " <" + sender_email + ">"
  end

  def recipient
    if recipient_name
      recipient_name + " <" + recipient_email + ">"
    else
      recipient_email
    end
  end

end
```

...but when I try to run standard model tests on it such as:

```
it { should validate_presence_of :sender_email }
```

...I get in return:

```
undefined method `reflect_on_association' for ContactMessage:Class
```

How can I set up these tests?

Comment: I would start looking here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/validate_presence_of_matcher.rb, check the your locally version of this file and inspect the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I see what's triggering it. Just don't know how to fix it or an alternate approach.